# What should the types of the edges be in this Graph ADT?

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

I'm working on a game as a class project, and it was suggested to me to use a Graph ADT to represent the set of territories on a world map such that each vertex is a territory, and the edges represent adjacent territories that the player can move between. I found a good Java library for the Graph ADT (JGraphT) but I have absolutely no idea what type the edges should be...

For example, the `Graph<V,E>` interface clearly requires me to define an object type for the vertex (which I think makes perfect sense to use my `Territory` type) but what should the edges be? I can't think of any object type that makes sense to use as an edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for example:

(1)

```
public class Border {
   // ... put here anything that's useful
   // e.g. length of border or type of border (land,sea,river)
}
```

The edge is actually the border
between the two territories.

So for me it makes sense your 
edge to be of class Border.

Another idea:

(2)

```
public class Distance {
   // ... put here anything that's useful
   // e.g. the distance between the two capitals
}
```

I usually represent those graphs in my head as if
the vertices are the capitals, and the edges are say
the roads between the capitals (of any two bordering
states/territories, I mean).

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I'm wondering if it's really necessary to have a defined type for the edges? I mean... a `Border` is neat, but there wouldn't be any use for such a class in my game.

Comment: I don't know your requirements. But e.g. tomorrow they may ask you to report the length of the border or something else, then that length would be a field in Border. If you don't need any special class like the Border I suggest, then just use Integer or Boolean :) You see, it all depends of your actual requirements.

Comment: I've updated my answer with another idea. But it all really depends on your requirements (and on those of the library you have chosen to use).

Comment: I like the boolean idea. It never occurred to me to have `True` if there is a link between the zones, and `False` otherwise...

Answer (score 2):

The jgrapht library contains an edge type called `DefaultWeightedEdge` if you need border weights (for distance, etc.)  Otherwise, you might just use the `DefaultEdge` class.

This is a more practical answer, ie these are actual classes within jgrapht that would suit your purposes. If you are looking for a more conceptual answer, I think that peter.petrov's answer regarding Border class is pretty much spot on.